# How to call closure function obtained through reflection?

Tags: go, reflection, closures

I'm experimenting with using Go's reflection library and have come to an issue I cannot figure out: How does one call on a function returned from calling a closure function via reflection? Is it possible to basically have a sequence of:

```
func (f someType) closureFn(i int) int {
  return func (x int) int {
     return x+i
  }
}
...

fn := reflect.ValueOf(&f).MethodByName("closureFn")
val := append([]reflect.Value{}, reflect.ValueOf(99))
fn0 := fn.Call(val)[0]
fn0p := (*func(int) int)(unsafe.Pointer(&f0))
m := (*fn0p)(100)
```

Which should get m to equal 199?

The following is the simplified code that demonstrates the issue. The call to the "dummy" anonymous function works ok, as does the reflective call to the closure. However attempts at calling on the closure return fail with a nil pointer (the flag set on the address of the Value in the debugger is 147, which comes down to addressable).
Any suggestions on what's going on, or if it's at all possible are welcome.

Link to playground: https://play.golang.org/p/0EPSCXKYOp0

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

// Typed Struct to hold the initialized jobs and group Filter function types
type GenericCollection struct {
    jobs []*Generic
}

type Generic func (target int) int

func main() {
    jjf := &GenericCollection{jobs: []*Generic{}}
    jjf.JobFactoryCl("Type", 20)
}


// Returns job function with closure on jobtype
func (f GenericCollection) Job_by_Type_Cl(jobtype int) (func(int) int) {
    fmt.Println("Job type is initialized to:", jobtype)

    // Function to return
    fc := func(target int) int {
        fmt.Println("inside JobType function")
            return target*jobtype
    }
    return fc
}

// Function factory
func (f GenericCollection) JobFactoryCl(name string, jobtype int) (jf func(int) int) {

    fn := reflect.ValueOf(&f).MethodByName("Job_by_" + name + "_Cl")
    val := append([]reflect.Value{}, reflect.ValueOf(jobtype))
    if fn != reflect.ValueOf(nil) {

        // Reflected function -- CALLING IT FAILS
        f0 := fn.Call(val)[0]
        f0p := unsafe.Pointer(&f0)

        //Local dummy anonymous function - CALLING IS OK
        f1 := func(i int) int {
            fmt.Println("Dummy got", i)
            return i+3
        }
        f1p := unsafe.Pointer(&f1)

        // Named function

        pointers := []unsafe.Pointer{f0p, f1p}

        // Try running f1 - OK
        f1r := (*func(int) int)(pointers[1])
        fmt.Println((*f1r)(1))
        (*f1r)(1)

        // Try calling f0 - FAILS. nil pointer dereference
        f0r := (*func(int) int)(pointers[0])
        fmt.Println((*f0r)(1))

        jf = *f0r
    }
    return jf
}
```

Comment: Don't just blindly try to convert things using `unsafe.Pointer`. I'm not sure exactly what you want here yet, but `Call` returns a slice of `reflect.Value`, so assert that however you want, or continue to use the reflected value.

Comment: It seems like a `map[string]func(int) int` would be much easier to use in the setup you've shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) the [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) to a function with the appropriate signature.  Call that function.

First example from the question:

```
type F struct{}

func (f F) ClosureFn(i int) func(int) int {
    return func(x int) int {
        return x + i
    }
}

func main() {
    var f F
    fn := reflect.ValueOf(&f).MethodByName("ClosureFn")

    fn0 := fn.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(99)})[0].Interface().(func(int) int)
    fmt.Println(fn0(100))

    // It's also possible to type assert directly 
    // the function type that returns the closure.
    fn1 := fn.Interface().(func(int) func(int) int)
    fmt.Println(fn1(99)(100))
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q_qHTdoyakC)

Second example from the question:

```
func (f GenericCollection) JobFactoryCl(name string, jobtype int) func(int) int {
    jf := reflect.ValueOf(&f).MethodByName("Job_by_" + name + "_Cl").Interface().(func(int) func(int) int)
    return jf(jobtype)
}

func main() {
   jjf := &GenericCollection{jobs: []*Generic{}}
   jf := jjf.JobFactoryCl("Type", 20)
   fmt.Println(jf(10))
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AReGoNl4VrO)

Comment: Thanks! Neat trick to wrap the value into an Interface and assert it as a function.
Small question: Why in my code didn't the pointer invocation work for the closure fn, while it did for the anonymous one? I.e. What's wrong with:

    f0r := (*func(int) int)(unsafe.Pointer(&f0))

   Then call using: (*f0r)(10)

Comment: f0 is a reflect.Value for a  function, not the function itself. You will need to add an offset within the reflect.Value to get the function. Don't do that though.  Use the supported API as shown in this answer.